# Would a T test be appropriate for determining the significance of an algorithm's results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, descriptive-statistics, algorithms

Say you have an algorithm which should yield a higher score when given two similar images and a lower value when given two images that do not resemble each other. Two sets of tests are run, one where pairs of similar images are given and the other where pairs of different images are given. Each test set contains 10 tests on complex images. The algorithm yields a higher score, on average, for the images which resemble each other. Although this seems to confirm a hypothesis that the algorithm works, statistical significance needs to be calculated. Would a T test be appropriate for this? If so, should the normal distribution of results from both test sets first be proven? Or, maybe another test altogether is more appropriate for this.

Comment: The key issues is: what is the distribution of the images? Or what assumptions are you willing to make on their distribution? Can you access a large number of them? If so, then you might employ laws of large number and central limit theorem to conduct inferences.

Comment: @ThreeDiag The images aren’t the data being tested. I would call them fixed, I think, so not even having a distribution. What is your interest in the image distribution?

Comment: Sorry, this was not clear, but you put some image in and your algorithm spits out some number. That's your whole data generating process. Assumptions need to be made about it in order to determine what type of test you can run and they will either be assumptions on the distribution of the DGP (e.g. it has a particular distribution) or assumption on property of the DGP (iid with finite mean and variance) so you can then conduct inference with a large enough sample.

Comment: Not clear about structure of data. Two-sample test? Sample size(s)? Can you show histogram, stripcharts (dotplots), or even boxplots of data? // If you want advice on something like t test vs Wikcoxon rank sum test, then best to provide information on size and shape of distributions of samples.